# R - Removing rows from dataframe based on multiple conditions for a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following example dataframe in R:

```
SampleID <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F")
Analyte <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "D1", "D2", "E1", "E1", "E2", "E2", "F1", "F2")
Fraction <- c("Dissolved", "Total", "Dissolved", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Dissolved", "Suspended", "Total", "Dissolved", "Suspended", "Total", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Dissolved", "Suspended", "Dissolved", "Suspended", "Dissolved", "Dissolved")
Concentration <- c(4.2, 5.6, 8.6, 11.2, 2.1, 9.6, 15.6, 28.7, 42.3, 18.3, 23.2, 48.6, 6.4, 28.8, 9.1, 32.5, 36.4, 24.5, 10.7, 3.4)
MyData <- data.frame(SampleID, Analyte, Fraction, Concentration)
```

`MyData`

```
   SampleID Analyte  Fraction Concentration
1         A      A1 Dissolved           4.2
2         A      A1     Total           5.6
3         A      A2 Dissolved           8.6
4         A      A2     Total          11.2
5         B      B1     Total           2.1
6         B      B2     Total           9.6
7         C      C1 Dissolved          15.6
8         C      C1 Suspended          28.7
9         C      C1     Total          42.3
10        C      C2 Dissolved          18.3
11        C      C2 Suspended          23.2
12        C      C2     Total          48.6
13        D      D1   Unknown           6.4
14        D      D2   Unknown          28.8
15        E      E1 Dissolved           9.1
16        E      E1 Suspended          32.5
17        E      E2 Dissolved          36.4
18        E      E2 Suspended          24.5
19        F      F1 Dissolved          10.7
20        F      F2 Dissolved           3.4
```

I would like to do the following:

1. For each `SampleID`, if an `Analyte` has a "Total" `Fraction` reported, retain only that row for the `Analyte` and remove rows with any other `Fraction` value (i.e., Dissolved, Suspended) for that `Analyte`.
2. If an `Analyte` for a `SampleID` includes both Dissolved and Suspended in the `Fraction` column (and no other values for `Fraction`), sum the concentrations for Dissolved and Suspended and add a row for that `Analyte` with the `Fraction` column labeled Total and the `Concentration` column listing the sum. Remove the original rows for Dissolved and Suspended for that `Analyte`.

So for the dataframe above, the two `Analytes` of `SampleID` "A" have Dissolved and Total, so I would want to remove the rows with the Dissolved `Fraction`. For `SampleID` "C", I would want to remove the Dissolved and Suspended `Fractions` of both `Analytes` and just keep the rows with Total. And lastly, for `SampleID` "E", the Dissolved and Suspended `Fractions` for each of the two `Analytes` would be summed together and the result would be a new row for each `Analyte` that represents the sum (relabeled as Total), and the rows associated with the Dissolved and Suspended `Fractions` would be removed.

The output of the above dataframe `MyData` would be the following:

```
   SampleID Analyte  Fraction Concentration
2         A      A1     Total           5.6
4         A      A2     Total          11.2
5         B      B1     Total           2.1
6         B      B2     Total           9.6
9         C      C1     Total          42.3
12        C      C2     Total          48.6
13        D      D1   Unknown           6.4
14        D      D2   Unknown          28.8
15        E      E1     Total          41.6 
17        E      E2     Total          60.9
19        F      F1 Dissolved          10.7
20        F      F2 Dissolved           3.4
```

Note that the example I have provided is just a small subset of a much larger dataset that includes hundreds of `SampleIDs`, but the `Fraction` column can only equal the values listed in the original dataframe above (i.e., Dissolved, Suspended, Total, or Unknown).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done as:

```
library(tidyverse)
MyData %>%
  pivot_wider(c(SampleID, Analyte),Fraction, values_from = Concentration) %>%
  mutate(Total = coalesce(Total, Dissolved + Suspended), 
         Dissolved = ifelse(is.na(Total)&is.na(Suspended), Dissolved, NA),
         Suspended = ifelse(is.na(Total)&is.na(Dissolved), Suspended, NA)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(SampleID, Analyte), values_drop_na = TRUE)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   SampleID Analyte name      value
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 A        A1      Total       5.6
 2 A        A2      Total      11.2
 3 B        B1      Total       2.1
 4 B        B2      Total       9.6
 5 C        C1      Total      42.3
 6 C        C2      Total      48.6
 7 D        D1      Unknown     6.4
 8 D        D2      Unknown    28.8
 9 E        E1      Total      41.6
10 E        E2      Total      60.9
11 F        F1      Dissolved  10.7
12 F        F2      Dissolved   3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution. It may sound a bit verbose but will also get the job done:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


MyData %>%
  group_split(SampleID, Analyte) %>%
  map(~ if("Total" %in% .x$Fraction) {
    .x %>% filter(Fraction == "Total")} else {
      .x
    }) %>%
  map(~ if(all(c("Dissolved", "Suspended") %in% .x$Fraction)) {
    add_row(.x, SampleID = .x$SampleID[1], Analyte = .x$Analyte[1], 
            Fraction = "Total", Concentration = sum(.x$Concentration))
  } else {
    .x
  }) %>%
  map_dfr(~ if("Total" %in% .x$Fraction) {
    .x %>% filter(Fraction == "Total")} else {
      .x
    })


# A tibble: 12 x 4
   SampleID Analyte Fraction  Concentration
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>             <dbl>
 1 A        A1      Total               5.6
 2 A        A2      Total              11.2
 3 B        B1      Total               2.1
 4 B        B2      Total               9.6
 5 C        C1      Total              42.3
 6 C        C2      Total              48.6
 7 D        D1      Unknown             6.4
 8 D        D2      Unknown            28.8
 9 E        E1      Total              41.6
10 E        E2      Total              60.9
11 F        F1      Dissolved          10.7
12 F        F2      Dissolved           3.4
```

Comment: Have you tried with `if/else if/else` in a single `map`

Comment: No. You mean instead of 3 `map` I nested them all in one?

Comment: What I find in your post is that you are looping 3 times with `map`.  You have a single `if/else` in each map.

Comment: Ok I will try it. I thought the result of each `map` is necessary for the following `map` so thought it may be better but it seems to cluttered now.

Comment: Or are you saying that it should be sequential after each filter

Comment: I thought circumstances were that each step would be better done sequential, but I will try to do it with one map and see how it fares.

Comment: In some cases, it is needed sequential i.e. `all(c("Dissolved", "Suspended")` may not be TRUE if it is not filtered.  I haven't run the whole code

Comment: Ok I tried it. The second filter apparently didn't work but it's not important I still have the same problem but it doesn't matter it may be a bug or something.

Comment: Are you saying this current code is giving errors?

Comment: Oh thank god! I don't have to be worried about OP running into a problem with my solution. Yes it's weird I noticed sometimes it doesn't run. Thank you for your time I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thank you for an alternative approach Anoushiravan and akrun!